# How do I export blender textures as png in cycles?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I just modeled this knife and I can't find how to export its texture as png.

[image: screenshot of a knife in Blender]

I searched a lot, but nothing seems to work. I tried baking it a few times, but all I got is a black UV map. And yes, it is unwrapped. When I baked it using combined bake type it baked the texture together with the light that was reflected of it.

[image: screesnhot of result]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://youtu.be/Tj-S5QAac3U